# Function that returns md and R code to be executed

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have several reports based on similar data that I run with `rmarkdown.` The final slide of each report is a "data provenance" slide that just gives details about the data, when it was pulled, report #, hash, etc. Right now, each report has individual final slides that I have to maintain separately and, as a result, if I have to make changes, I have to change the slide in each report. This is cumbersome.

I'd like to be able to have a function that returns slide text and `R` code that gets evaluated at run time and rendered as markdown and `R` code, but I'm having a problem getting that set up. This is what I have so far:

```
library(git2r)
library(dplyr)

base <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date(), 
                   DateTime = Sys.time()) # Simple example data
params <- list(version = "0.0.5")
tmp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".rds") # Write so that I can hash
base %>% saveRDS(tmp_file)

data_provenance <- function(){

    print("* Data as of: `r base %>% arrange(desc(Date)) %>% select(DateTime) %>% slice(1) %>% .$DateTime`
           * Dataset: `r hash(tmp_file)`
           * Report version: `r params$version`")

}
```

When I run `rmarkdown` on this

```
## Data, test

Report details

`r data_provenance()`
```

all I get is a slide with the title and "Report details" line, but none of the output from the `data provenance()` function. The `data_provenance()` stuff does print to the console, however.

I've used the `print()` statement in a conditional function earlier in this report:

````
## Overview

```{r neg_ideas_chunk, echo = FALSE}

neg_ideas <- nrow(base) > 0

```    

`r if(neg_ideas)(print("* Negative ideas removed:"))`
````

and the `r if(...)(...)` populates the slide without error.

Can I have a separate function that combines `.md` and `R` code in it's return and have it run and rendered succesfully in an `.Rmd` file? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

How about this example presentation:

````
---
title: "example"
author: "Luke C"
date: "December 11, 2017"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Data, test

Report details

```{r}
data_provenance()
```
````

That you can then run using a modified version of your R script (assuming the .Rmd and R files are in the same directory, which is also the working directory):

```
library(dplyr)
library(git2r)

base <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date(), 
                   DateTime = Sys.time()) # Simple example data
params <- list(version = "0.0.5")
tmp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".rds") # Write so that I can hash
base %>% saveRDS(tmp_file)

data_provenance <- function(){
  x <- sapply(list(
    paste("* Data as of:", 
          base %>% arrange(desc(Date)) %>% select(DateTime) %>% slice(1) %>% .$DateTime, 
          "\n"),
    paste("* Dataset:", hash(tmp_file), "\n"),
    paste("* Report version:", params$version)), 
    paste, collapse = "")
  cat(x, sep = "")
}

data_provenance()

rmarkdown::render("example_presentation.Rmd")
```

Output looks like:

[image]

However, if you're not rendering your markdown files from an R script, any reason you couldn't just define the function in the markdown file itself?

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so this is a bit janky as it:

- Rewrites your .Rmd file line-by-line to a temporary file
- Inserts the needed lines from your `data_provenance` after the "Report details" flag
- Renders the temporary .Rmd file

So, with this presentation setup, with a `Data, test` slide blank except for "Report details":

````
---
title: "example"
author: "Luke C"
date: "December 11, 2017"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Data, test

Report details
````

And the same basic setup as before, with a modified `data-provenance`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(git2r)

base <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date(), 
                   DateTime = Sys.time()) # Simple example data
params <- list(version = "0.0.5")
tmp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".rds") # Write so that I can hash
base %>% saveRDS(tmp_file)

data_provenance <- function(){
  paste(
    paste("* Data as of:", 
          base %>% arrange(desc(Date)) %>% select(DateTime) %>% slice(1) %>% .$DateTime, 
          "\n"),
    paste("* Dataset:", hash(tmp_file), "\n"),
    paste("* Report version:", params$version))
}
```

Now, a function that takes in the filename and the function that outputs whatever data details you want, structured as `data_provenance` above:

```
render_dynamic_prov <- function(filename, det_fun){
  f.out.name = paste(gsub(".Rmd", "", filename), ".html", sep = "")
  file(description = filename, open = "r")
  file(description = "outfile_temp.Rmd", open = "w")
  for (i in readLines(filename)) {
    if (i == "Report details") {
      write(x = paste(i, "\n"), file = "outfile_temp.Rmd", append = TRUE)
      write(x = det_fun, file = "outfile_temp.Rmd", append = TRUE)
    } else {
      write(x = i, file = "outfile_temp.Rmd", append = TRUE)
    }
  }
  closeAllConnections()
  rmarkdown::render("outfile_temp.Rmd", output_file = f.out.name)
  file.remove("outfile_temp.Rmd")
}
```

Now you can call the function with the .Rmd file you want to use and the data details function you want:

```
render_dynamic_prov("example_presentation.Rmd", data_provenance())
```

That generates a slide like:

[image]

But, if you now make a new data details function, like:

```
data_provenance_fake <- function(){
  paste(
    paste("* Data as of:", 
          base %>% 
            arrange(desc(Date)) %>% 
            select(DateTime) %>% 
            slice(1) %>% 
            .$DateTime),
    paste("* Dataset:", hash(tmp_file)),
    paste("* Report version:", params$version),
    paste("* Fake number:", runif(n = 1)),
    paste("* Here is another bullet:", rnorm(1))
    , sep = "\n")
}
```

you can run the `render_dynamic_prov` function again, with this new data details function, to output a different slide:

```
render_dynamic_prov("example_presentation.Rmd", data_provenance_fake())
```

[image]

Comment: This is great inasmuch as it just pastes all the information together and is printed from within a code chunk. Ideally, though, the text and `*` would show up as markdown (with the `*` printed as a bullet rather than a `*`).

Here's what the current output of the final slide looks like: https://i.imgur.com/KcTNzXw.png 

In other words, I need the output from `data_provenance()` to be rendered as markdown, not as the output from a code chunk.

Comment: @Steven Ok, see if my edits get you closer to what you're after.

Comment: Well, the named list is handy but if I wanted to add something to that final slide, I'd still have to update each report individually AND the function itself. Perhaps I wasn't as specific in my original question as I could have been.

Comment: @Steven- no, you're right, I spaced on that (pretty critical) detail. I don't know a way to have R chunk output interpreted as markdown text, I'll be watching this question to see if someone has a solution. Cheers!

Comment: @Steven - I changed my mind, maybe I do know how. See my edits again, this *should* allow you to modify only your R script.